# A problem out of reach for forever

Tags: logic

Given any really large number $x$, such as the busy beaver number $x=BB(BB(99))$, can we construct a proposition such that we know it has a proof or a disproof, but we also know the shortest such proof or disproof is longer then $x$ symbols?

Comment: Not so Git Gud. If the parentheses are put back in (say to the left), so the premiss is of the form $(\varphi \land 1 = 1)$ then exactly ONE application of conjunction elimination is needed to get the conclusion!

Comment: One might also reasonably require that the proposition is "short" compared to $x$ itself.

Comment: @PeterSmith Right. Missed that. Comment deleted. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

There is a beautiful paper by George Boolos related to this, called "A Curious Inference" (in his collected papers called *Logic, Logic, and Logic*).

Suppose $s$ is a one-place function sign, and $f$ a two-place function sign. And take the five axioms

> $\forall n \, f(n, 1) = s1$
>
> $\forall x\, f(1, sx) = ssf(1, x)$
>
> $\forall n\forall x\, f(sn, sx) = f(n, f(sn, x))$
>
> $D1$
>
> $\forall x(Dx \to Dsx)$

What's going on here is that $f$ is defined to be Ackermann-like (if we think of $s$ as successor) and the last two axioms say that $D$ is hereditary down an $s$ sequence. So we'll have the likes of

> $Df(ssss1,ssss1)$.

But it will take in the order of Ackermann(5,5) steps to get there in first-order logic. And if that isn't a big enough number for you, just choose target

> $Df(ss\ldots ss1,ss\ldots ss1)$.

so the first-order proof has the order of Ackermann($n$,$n$) steps!

Now the curious thing of Boolos's title is that while the first-order proof would have *vastly* more steps then particles in the known universe, we can write down a *second-order* derivation in a couple of pages (regimenting our informal reasoning that the conclusion does indeed follow).

Answer (score 4):

If you have a short definite *description* of $x$, then you can use Gödel's construction to create a sentence that says "I have no proof in less than $x$ symbols". This sentence has to be true, because if it was false then it would (by itself) have a short proof, and things that are false have no proofs, short or long.

However, if that sentence is true, it must be *provably* true, because we can "just" check all strings of up to $x$ symbols and see whether one of them happens to prove it.

The only caveat is that your description of $x$ needs to allow us to *know* when we have checked long enough strings. Therefore $BB(BB(99))$ is not a likely candidate, because we can't know when we've reached that number exactly. As long as your $x$ comes from a well-defined *computable* function you should be fine, though.

Comment: What if I require that we cant construct a valid argument (as you did here) that its false or true in less then x symbols either? And why doesnt your reasoning thats its provable constitute a proof in less then x symbols?

Comment: The argument contains the hidden assumption that the axiom system cannot prove falsehoods. So the argument isn't actually formalizable in the axiom system we're speaking about.